# How to assign controls in an ItemControl to the values in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl that has an ItemsSource that is an ObservableCollection.

The Collection is populated with Student objects each time a button is selected.

The ItemsControl will look like this as it is populated

```
[------] 1
[------] 2
[------] 3
```

Where the [----] is a Grid and the number is a Label.
I actually want to set the Label content to the items I have in another ObservableCollection.

So suppose this ObservableCollection is
"Physics", "Calculus", "English" then I want the Labels to read in the ItemsSource as "Physics, "Calculus", and "English"

My XAML is something like

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentCollection}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5, 0, 15, 0" Height="120">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Content ="" 
// This is where I want to set the values of the dynamically built Label   to    the items in the Collection.
                                           FontFamily="Helvetica" FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="16"/>
```

Comment: How are you storing those ClassIDs ? in a collection ?, or are they generated dynamically some how !

Comment: Generated dynamically, they're the index of where they sit in the Collection.

Comment: Could you add that part of the code to your question pls ?

Comment: Your Binding doesn't make sense. Label should use ClassID directly and if you only want to display number in that control then use `TextBlock` instead. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ClassID}"/>` if you want to have last number hidden then use a converter and compare if the student classID == StudentCollection.Count - 1 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use TextBlocks instead of Labels but this should be similar...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StudentCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            ....
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubListText}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And your ViewModels:

```
public class ListViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentCollection => ...;
}

public class Student {
    public ObservableCollection<Stuff> Stuff => ... ; //["Physics", ...]
    public string SubListText => string.Join(", ", Stuff);
}
```

or you can add another ItemsControl like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StudentCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            ....
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                     </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```