# Two way binding to list of lists in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to make two-way binding to my ListBox which contains a 2D array of double. For that i'm using a custom item template, and value converter which convert my 2D array to list of lists.
**The problem is that works only in one way.**

My list box:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource double2dArray}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding CoEmergenceProbability,
                       Converter={StaticResource double2DArrayConverter},
                       Mode=TwoWay,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}},
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
                      }"
 />
```

Converter:

```
public class Double2DArrayToListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new List<List<double>>();
        }
        double[][] values = (double[][])value;
        List<List<double>> res = new List<List<double>>(values.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            res.Add(values[i].ToList());
        }
        return res;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<List<double>> values = (List<List<double>>)value;
        double[][] res = new double[values.Count][];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            res[i] = values[i].ToArray();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Custom templates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="editableDouble">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" Width="70" Height="25" Margin="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="double2dArray">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource editableDouble}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That isn't a 2D array it's a jagged array. In C# a 2D array is written `T[,]`. If you are going to use a jagged array why not just a `List<List<T>>` in the first place and forgo the conversion?

Comment: *"I know that two-way binding is possible only if both properties are dependency property"*. That's a misunderstanding. While the target property of a Binding needs to be a dependency property, the source property doesn't, even if it supposed to by set be the Binding.

Comment: To expand on Clemens point. You could have a 2d array of an object that implemented inotifypropertychanged instead of dependency objects. A dp binding is faster than the property on a poco though and if you have many of these then the do might well be a better solution for that reason.

Comment: You could try making the dp bind twoway by default. It's one of the registration metadata options.

Comment: *"A dp binding is faster"* is utter nonsense and irrelevant in the context of the question.

Comment: It might be irrelevant but dp bindings are faster. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-data-binding

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining to me about dp binding. In my case I don't have a lot of properties, so I don't need to use dp binding.

Comment: You could greatly simply this by binding the ListBox to a collection of objects with a `double[]` or `ICollection<double>` (or similar) property. The converter would be at the Text Binding in the ItemTemplate, and instead of converting an array of arrays it would simply convert a double collection from/to string.

Answer (score 0):

A TwoWay Binding on ItemSource is logically useless... If you want to change the Items you have to Change your Model and the view updates automatically. You will never have it the other way around!

TwoWay Bindings are for UI Elements where the User can change the value from the UI. Like in a TextBox.

Maybe you want to get something like in this question: [How to assign controls in an ItemControl to the values in an ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387956/how-to-assign-controls-in-an-itemcontrol-to-the-values-in-an-observablecollectio/49417368#49417368)